# ireport to excel like reportviewer

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Is there any way to make an ireport export to excel as Microsoft ReportViewer does?

I've always used Microsoft ReportViewer and I found an enormous difference between them, I like the way it work but I have to do this program in java and jasperreports is the best report engine Ive found.

Actually I've found that I can export to excel from java manually using code and using the Apache POI library, but I have to basically draw in code how I want the spreadsheet to be made.

Is there anything that I can do about it?, or is there any other report engine that I'm missing? or maybe any configuration parameter?

please help! and sorry about my english

Thanks in advance :)

PS: By the way its a desktop application and it only needs to work in windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use at least two *Java* frameworks for working with *JasperReports*: 
*[JasperReports API](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/index.html)* and *[DynamicJasper API](http://dynamicjasper.com/documentation-examples/api-docs/)*.

You can find a lot of samples in [Jasper Reports distribution package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jasperreports/files/jasperreports/JasperReports%204.5.0/) (look in *`%jasperreports%\demo\samples`* folder).

The sample of *Java* code for exporting report to *MS Excel* format using *JasperReports API*:

```java
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, pswd);

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportJRXMLFile);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, connection);

JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, outputFile);
```

The another variant to build report in *Excel* format is to use *[JasperServer](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-server)* - ready for use web-application for building reports. It has many other exporters (*pdf*, *docx*, *txt*, *xml*, etc.).

The *[iReport](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer)* is *NetBeans* based GUI designer for constructing report's templates (*jrxml* files).
The *[Jaspersoft Studio](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio)* is similar designer based on *Eclipse*.